# Why ::selection:first-child doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Why this code doesn't work?

```
::selection:first-child{
        background-color: #ffa563;
}
```

This works fine - **:first-child:last-child** (when element is first child AND last child)

Comment: `::selection` is not an element. try `:first-child::selection` should work I think.

Comment: What would ::selection:first-child even mean? There is only ever at most one selection at a time, isn't there?

Comment: @Mr_Green thank you, it works. But why we must use pseudo-class first?

Comment: @BoltClock — It could contain multiple elements though

Comment: @yatongen we can't apply pseudo class to pseudo elements. afaik.

Comment: @Quentin: A selection can span any number of elements, but the ::selection pseudo-element never contains other elements. Each element generates its own ::selection pseudo-element, which may or may not be rendered over descendant elements. Perhaps my original statement should have been "There is only ever at most one selection per element at a time".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::selection` is not an element. try `:first-child::selection` should work.

```css
:first-child::selection {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>First Child</div>
<div>Second Child</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mixing up pseudo class and pseudo element. `::selection` is pseudo element, so it doesn't contain anything and only work with few css attributes.

If you want to style selection in first child, use `:first-child::selection` instead

Answer (score 0):

When you try to use a selector like "::selection" or ":first-child" it´s better if you specify the container.

```
<div>
  <p>text 1</p>
  <p>text 2</p>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
div p:first-child::selection {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}
```

the first 'p' will show different if you select.

Comment: It's better, but not required, and irrelevant to the question in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `:first-child` will never adjust to the selectors listed before. For example, `p:first-child` will not match for a structure of `<div><h1></h1><p></p></div>` since the `p` is the second tag.

Similarly, a `::selection:first-child` would also not match the first tag in the selection but only a selected element that is also a first child. And at that point, it’s equivalent to `:first-child::selection`.

As for why it doesn’t work, `::selection` is a pseudo *element*. Using it creates some kind of an element that is matched. But that pseudo element never exists in the DOM, so it cannot be the first child of something. So the whole selector will not match.